# running makefile created by cmake with gcc compiler

Tags: cmake, gnu-make

I'm experimenting with cmake. Let's say I have my source directory with a HelloWorld.c file and an CMakeList.txt with following conent:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.6)

    PROJECT( HelloWorld )

    ADD_EXECUTABLE( helloworld HelloWorld.c )
```

When I invoke cmake (with minGW generator) within this directory, everything ist ok and the build tree is generated which contains also a "Makefile" . My questions is now: This generated makefile can be also used as an usual manualy created makefile. For example when I just type 'make' in the command promtp, the project should build. But I see nothing, only:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

this output. What I don't understand properly here?

I'm generating the build tree using the cmake GUI and get this output:

```
The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.1
The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.1
Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
Configuring done
Generating done
```

So, this means, in my build directory, all relevant stuff for the gcc compiler is correct is generated?
but, what i also can not understand, when I run cmake from my source directory where HelloWorld.c and the CMakeList.Txt is located i get this output:

```
C:\testworkspace\cmake>cmake C:\testworkspace\cmake
-- Building for: Visual Studio 10 2010
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.40219.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.40219.1
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10 2010
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10 2010 -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 10 2010
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 10 2010 -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - failed
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/testworkspace/cmake

C:\testworkspace\cmake>
```

Why cmake takes the Visual Studio compiler? In the GUI the MinGW compiler is configured!?

Comment: are you in the same folder where the `Makefile` is ?

Comment: yes, I'm running make exactly from it's folder :S

Comment: What compiler are you using? You talked about minGW but your make seems to link microsoft `nmake`

Comment: What's about `make helloworld`? Or `make` and hitting the tabulator key?

Comment: I'm using gcc compiler. Also when i look into the CMakeCach.Txt file, gcc is specified as a compiler. But what is strange, when I look into the generated makefile, there is nothing that regards to a gcc compiler .. hmm

Comment: @milexy86: It seems you have mess of different configurations in your source tree. Try to remove all generated files(`Makefile` and others) from source dir, and make *out-of-source* build: `mkdir build`, `cd build`, `cmake ..`.

Comment: @usr1234567: No, its the same behaviour

Comment: @Tsyvarev: I deleted everything which was created and than again created the new build tree with MinGW generator but the same behaviour. What do you mean with out-of -source build? what is the exact command?

Comment: *out-of-source* build means calling `cmake` not from source directory, but from another one. Only last cmake parameter should be changed.

Comment: Yes i tried this, but in this case cmake generates a new build tree with an totally different compiler (visual studio in this case). Also when I try to specify gcc as default compiler with command: cmake -G MinGW Makefile -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER= g++ C:\testworkspace\cmake", I get the message:  "CMake Error: Could not create named generator MinGW"  ... realy strange

Comment: I don't have MinGW installed to test, but on this last command you probably need `cmake -G "MinGW Makefile" ... `, that is, with the double quotes. Also, do you do all this work from a MinGW shell or a Windows command window?

Comment: @Alain: Yes, this was exactly my problem. So, I have to run cmake -G "MSYS Makefile" and not cmake -G "MinGW Makefile" because of the problem with "sh.exe" (http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_MinGW_Compiler_Issues)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved.
So when I'm configuring the build tree using the  Cmake GUI, I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-    3.3/Modules/CMakeMinGWFindMake.cmake:22 (message):
  sh.exe was found in your PATH, here:

  C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/sh.exe

  For MinGW make to work correctly sh.exe must NOT be in your path.

  Run cmake from a shell that does not have sh.exe in your PATH.

  If you want to use a UNIX shell, then use MSYS Makefiles.

  Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (PROJECT)
```

When I just remove the C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/sh.exe path from the Cmake GUI, it works and build tree is generated with the MinGW generator.

So if I would like to do this procedure via the command line inside my source directory,  I have to invoke **cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles"** and not -G "MinGW Makefiles"! This behaviour is explained here: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_MinGW_Compiler_Issues

Now i just run **"make"** from the same directory where my build tree is generated and it works.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to provide the actual information here and not just a link. [Link-only answers are not considered good answers and will probably be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).